# difficulty changing the focus on the text box by materialize

Tags: html, css, materialize

With the focus in check and the label moving to the top, I can't find where this css is being changes, and how to take control over it.

The real focus here is this

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
     <i class="material-icons prefix ">account_circle</i>
     <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate"
       </input>
     <label for="icon_prefix">Character Name</label>
</div>
```

In chrome inspection I thought this might work

```
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

but alas it did not, and frustrated spending more time than I should. I am here.

Here is the whole html snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>Input Change</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
      <div id="root">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
            <i class="material-icons prefix ">account_circle</i>
            <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate ">
            </input>
            <label for="icon_prefix">Character Name</label>
        </div>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the css

```
/* https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html */
/* label focus color */
.input-field input:focus + label {
    color: black !important;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid red !important; */
  }
  #icon_prefix {
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid red !important; */
    /* box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red !important */
  }
  .active {
      color: black !important;
  }

.validate{
    /* border-bottom: red !important; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid red !important; */
}
  /* label underline focus color */
  .row .input-field input:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black !important
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle. The issue is when you click the text box, that highlighted *greenish* line is the one I'm trying to target. In inspection I couldn't seem to figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/robstao/b1goj7q2/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is correct. The only thing is that you also need to add this to your code:

"box-shadow: none !important;"

There is also a green box shadow being applied. If you prefer to make it black but similar to the material one, you can always increase the border width from 1 to 2px.

As a note, the label is moving because there is a class being dynamically applied to it (also to the icon) when we have focus on the input ("active").

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of ways to perform this task. Some are recommended and some are easy to go with.

1: You can go to the materialize.css file and check on line 13 or so you will find the code below

```
input:not([type]):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=password]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=email]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=url]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=time]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=date]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=number]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type=search]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
border-bottom: 1px solid #26a69a;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #26a69a;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #26a69a;
```

}

change the color values to the primary color of you site.

Note: you will find other lot of global css code at the top of materialize css file. try non min version.

2: If you want you can over ride the materialize css code. example below

```
input {
border-bottom: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

3: you can go with the most recommended way to recompile the sass file of materialize css and change the values there. You will find the variables [here](https://materializecss.com/sass.html)

https://jsfiddle.net/bilalkhan891/bf0jtqLk/1/